# Covers of X in the Stone-Cech compacticatoin

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that  $X$ is a Hausdorff completely regular space.  $X$ embeds homeomorphically into its Stone-Cech compactifaction $\beta{X}$ and is dense in $\beta{X}$; we can identify  $X \subset \beta{X}$.  Suppose we have a cover $\mathcal{V}$ of  $X$ by $\beta{X}$-open sets.  Must $\mathcal{V}$ also cover all of $\beta{X}$ (and therefore have a finite subcover)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No: $\beta\omega_1$ is (homeomorphic to) $\omega_1+1$, and $\omega_1$ is open in $\omega_1+1$.

**Added:** More generally, if $X$ is locally compact, then $X$ is open in $\beta X$, so any cover of $X$ by $X$-open sets is a cover of $X$ by $\beta X$-open sets. In particular, $\beta\omega$ (or $\beta\Bbb N$, if you prefer) is an example: $\omega$ is locally compact and therefore open in $\beta\omega$.